# Android/Java sequence of serially executed tasks

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, concurrency, android-asynctask

How can I have a sequence of tasks that run one after another (Serially). I'm not using `AsyncTasks`, but the `loopj AsyncHttpClient`, but the question applies to other tasks as well.

The way it's structured is: Application has main method that performs multiple async calls. These calls are mutually serial, one must be run after another.

- `Main()` calls `FuncA()` which fires an async request. Control is returned to `Main()`
- The request handler calls `OnFuncAComplete()`, which triggers `Main()` to proceed:
- `Main()` calls `FuncB()` which fires an async request. Control is returned to `Main()`
- The request handler calls `OnFuncBComplete()`, which triggers `Main()` to proceed:
- rinse, repeat

How can I write main to perform all these functions in lock-step, how can I pause `Main()` and in `OnFuncXComplete` "trigger" main back into action? My first thought was with ReentrantLock's, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: I know I could just call `FuncB()` from `OnFuncAComplete()`, but then I'm getting down into callback hell and I want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be more than one solution for this. One possibility is to use [SynchronousQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) for transferring tasks between your Main and a processor. AsyncTask probably will not be needed, instead your tasks can extend runnables and no need to make callbacks to "unlock" Main()

1. Create a processing thread that runs a loop and polls SynchronousQueue instance (possibly with timeout). Each element obtained from the queue is a Runnable that the processor thread just executes.
2. In your Main() you call FuncA(SynchronousQueue q, <...>), FuncB(SynchronousQueue q, <...>), etc. sequentially
3. Each of FuncX() inserts its runnable task into the queue (q)
4. Make sure that you can nicely finish your thread once there is no more tasks to run

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `IntentService`. It is a Worker service that has only one bg thread an requests are enqueued and processed in a FCFS manner. Responses from service to your Main can be delivered via a `BroadcastReceiver` that your Main should have registered beforehand.